# Handling relationships between fields

Tags: django, django-models

Here is my model:-

```
class Form(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
description = models.TextField()
created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
starts_on = models.DateTimeField()
ends_on = models.DateTimeField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

I want to restrict created_on to be always less than equals to start_on, and similarily ends_on to be greater than equals to starts_on. What are the options available in Django to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can perform validation in the [**`.clean()`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) to perform validation. This will *not* run when you create/update an object in a view yourself, but a `ModelForm` will call this to validate.

Since Django-2.2, you can also add a `CheckConstraint`, these will be enforced at the *database level*. A database does not per see enforces this:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db.models import F, Q

class Form(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    starts_on = models.DateTimeField()
    ends_on = models.DateTimeField()

    def clean(self):
        if self.created_on > self.starts_on:
            raise ValidationError('Starts on should be after create on')
        if self.starts_on > self.ends_on:
            raise ValidationError('Ends on should be after starts on')
        return super().clean()

    class Meta:
        # since Django-2.2
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(created_on__lte=F('starts_on')),
                name='create_lte_starts'
            ),
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(starts_on__lte=F('ends_on')),
                name='starts_lte_ends'
            )
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```